# Rationalizing a numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble rationalizing a numerator with radicals. After multiplying the conjugate I get 0. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{2+y} + \sqrt{2 - y}}{y} & = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2+y} + \sqrt{2 - y}}{y}\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2+y} - \sqrt{2 - y}}{\sqrt{2+y} - \sqrt{2 - y}}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2+y}\sqrt{2+y} - \sqrt{2+y}\sqrt{2-y} + \sqrt{2-y}\sqrt{2+y} - \sqrt{2-y}\sqrt{2-y}}{y\sqrt{2+y} - y\sqrt{2-y}}\\
& =\frac{2 + y - 2 - y}{y\sqrt{2+y} - y\sqrt{2-y}} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: Put brackets around $(2-y)$ in the numerator of your last line.  The numerator then becomes $2y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful:

$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2\implies $$

$$\left(\sqrt{2+y}+\sqrt{2-y}\right)\left(\sqrt{2+y}-\sqrt{2-y}\right)=(2+y)-(2-y)=2+y-2+y=2y$$

you forgot to change the second$\,-y\,$ into $\,+y\,$ ....

Comment: Ah, a silly mistake on my part. Thank you.

Comment: If you're doing this in $\Bbb C$ that works fine otherwise a bit of care should be taken after the multiplication you should get $$|2+y| - |2-y|$$ and then analyze the three possible branches

Comment: @JohnC , first the question's level points towards a very low probability the OP is dealing with complex analysis, and second: I think you meant "If you're doing this in $\,\Bbb R\;$ that..."

Comment: @Don Antonio , I know that's why I said "_otherwise_" I was just pointing out that you can't always _just_ cancel out the roots (In this case it doesn't make a difference since the domain restrictions imposed by the rest of the expression makes everything work out)